# What JSON library works well for you in .NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'd be interested in hearing what JSON library folks in the community have been using inside of .NET?  I have a need to parse/serialize some JSON object graphs from inside .NET (C#) to actual .NET types.  I could roll my own, but if there are some solid libraries folks have used, I'd like to hear your comments.  I saw the list of libraries on the json.org site, but it's a fairly big list and the community is usually good at vetting out the contenders from the pretenders

Any details (pros/cons) of your experience with the library would be incredibly helpful. -- thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

I've used [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) with success in the past.

Example from the site:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": new Date(1230422400000),
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

Comment: Just for the record, in case anyone comes across this, `"Expiry": new Date(1230422400000)` is **not** valid JSON.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir, yes.  JSON.NET is a pretty good library, but that part is a bad example.  I'm not sure if that's still the default behavior, but as this (old) [article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx) explains you can use [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) to serialize to/from a (valid) ISO date string instead.

Answer (score 19):

There are at least two built into the framework.

The newer : [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx)

and the older : [System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.aspx)

I prefer to not have dependencies on 3rd party libraries. I work with JSON every day and have never needed anything more than what already exists in the framework.

Comment: Works nice for encoding, but for decoding into a fixed class hierarchy that didn't work well with the dynamic stuff it needed to decode, so for that I used System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(string). I've also used it for encoding.

Comment: For smaller objects those work fine.  Once you get to larger objects or heavy use the perforance of the built in libraries is lacking.  We shaved more than 50% off of the serialization and deserialization simply by switching to JSON.Net.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote my own JSON serializer using [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) in the `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` assembly [which is a component of WCF included in .NET 3.5 as a standard assembly, and in the .NET 3.5 SP1 Client Profile] (in .NET 4.0 and Silverlight 4, it's been moved to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`).

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class JsonObjectSerializer 
{
    public string Serialize<T>(T instance) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, instance);

            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string serialized) where T : class
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                writer.Write(serialized);
                writer.Flush();

                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                return serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tweaked it to an extension method for myself, thanks :)

Comment: How do I prevent the DataContractJsonSerializer from returning XML instead of JSON?

Answer (score 4):

You should also try my ServiceStack [JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) - it's the fastest .NET JSON serializer at the moment [based on the benchmarks of the leading JSON serializers](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) and supports serializing any POCO Type, DataContracts, Lists/Dictionaries, Interfaces, Inheritance, Late-bound objects including anonymous types, etc.

Basic Example:

```
Customer customer = new Customer { Name="Joe Bloggs", Age=31 };
string json = customer.ToJson();
Customer fromJson = json.FromJson<Customer>(json);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is released under the AGPL license, meaning it can **only** be used in open-source software, even if you're developing a website.

Comment: v3 is BSD licensed whilst the latest v4 is also available under a [commercial license](https://servicestack.net/text#pricing).

Comment: Where is v3 available at? **\[Edit]** Nevermind, found it: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/releases/tag/v3-snapshot

Comment: @mythz Are you sure your library can be faster than [Jil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil)? ;) Btw, your benchmark link is broken...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json Namespace included with .NET 3.5.

Comment: For those who are interested, it lives in System.ServiceModel.Web

Comment: -1 Until I figure out what this adds over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571168/what-json-library-works-well-for-you-in-net/571200#571200 which was posted before this

Comment: +1 for including the framework version, and being *concise*

Answer (score 2):

I typed "json" into google and the top hit was json.org, which leads to what looks like a good single utility class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Procurios.Public
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class encodes and decodes JSON strings.
    /// Spec. details, see http://www.json.org/
    /// 
    /// JSON uses Arrays and Objects. These correspond here to the datatypes ArrayList and Hashtable.
    /// All numbers are parsed to doubles.
    /// </summary>
    public class JSON
    {
        public const int TOKEN_NONE = 0; 
        public const int TOKEN_CURLY_OPEN = 1;
        public const int TOKEN_CURLY_CLOSE = 2;
        public const int TOKEN_SQUARED_OPEN = 3;
        public const int TOKEN_SQUARED_CLOSE = 4;
        public const int TOKEN_COLON = 5;
        public const int TOKEN_COMMA = 6;
        public const int TOKEN_STRING = 7;
        public const int TOKEN_NUMBER = 8;
        public const int TOKEN_TRUE = 9;
        public const int TOKEN_FALSE = 10;
        public const int TOKEN_NULL = 11;

        private const int BUILDER_CAPACITY = 2000;

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the string json into a value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json">A JSON string.</param>
        /// <returns>An ArrayList, a Hashtable, a double, a string, null, true, or false</returns>
        public static object JsonDecode(string json)
        {
            bool success = true;

            return JsonDecode(json, ref success);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the string json into a value; and fills 'success' with the successfullness of the parse.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json">A JSON string.</param>
        /// <param name="success">Successful parse?</param>
        /// <returns>An ArrayList, a Hashtable, a double, a string, null, true, or false</returns>
        public static object JsonDecode(string json, ref bool success)
        {
            success = true;
            if (json != null) {
                char[] charArray = json.ToCharArray();
                int index = 0;
                object value = ParseValue(charArray, ref index, ref success);
                return value;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a Hashtable / ArrayList object into a JSON string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json">A Hashtable / ArrayList</param>
        /// <returns>A JSON encoded string, or null if object 'json' is not serializable</returns>
        public static string JsonEncode(object json)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(BUILDER_CAPACITY);
            bool success = SerializeValue(json, builder);
            return (success ? builder.ToString() : null);
        }

        protected static Hashtable ParseObject(char[] json, ref int index, ref bool success)
        {
            Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
            int token;

            // {
            NextToken(json, ref index);

            bool done = false;
            while (!done) {
                token = LookAhead(json, index);
                if (token == JSON.TOKEN_NONE) {
                    success = false;
                    return null;
                } else if (token == JSON.TOKEN_COMMA) {
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                } else if (token == JSON.TOKEN_CURLY_CLOSE) {
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                    return table;
                } else {

                    // name
                    string name = ParseString(json, ref index, ref success);
                    if (!success) {
                        success = false;
                        return null;
                    }

                    // :
                    token = NextToken(json, ref index);
                    if (token != JSON.TOKEN_COLON) {
                        success = false;
                        return null;
                    }

                    // value
                    object value = ParseValue(json, ref index, ref success);
                    if (!success) {
                        success = false;
                        return null;
                    }

                    table[name] = value;
                }
            }

            return table;
        }

        protected static ArrayList ParseArray(char[] json, ref int index, ref bool success)
        {
            ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

            // [
            NextToken(json, ref index);

            bool done = false;
            while (!done) {
                int token = LookAhead(json, index);
                if (token == JSON.TOKEN_NONE) {
                    success = false;
                    return null;
                } else if (token == JSON.TOKEN_COMMA) {
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                } else if (token == JSON.TOKEN_SQUARED_CLOSE) {
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                    break;
                } else {
                    object value = ParseValue(json, ref index, ref success);
                    if (!success) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    array.Add(value);
                }
            }

            return array;
        }

        protected static object ParseValue(char[] json, ref int index, ref bool success)
        {
            switch (LookAhead(json, index)) {
                case JSON.TOKEN_STRING:
                    return ParseString(json, ref index, ref success);
                case JSON.TOKEN_NUMBER:
                    return ParseNumber(json, ref index, ref success);
                case JSON.TOKEN_CURLY_OPEN:
                    return ParseObject(json, ref index, ref success);
                case JSON.TOKEN_SQUARED_OPEN:
                    return ParseArray(json, ref index, ref success);
                case JSON.TOKEN_TRUE:
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                    return true;
                case JSON.TOKEN_FALSE:
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                    return false;
                case JSON.TOKEN_NULL:
                    NextToken(json, ref index);
                    return null;
                case JSON.TOKEN_NONE:
                    break;
            }

            success = false;
            return null;
        }

        protected static string ParseString(char[] json, ref int index, ref bool success)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(BUILDER_CAPACITY);
            char c;

            EatWhitespace(json, ref index);

            // "
            c = json[index++];

            bool complete = false;
            while (!complete) {

                if (index == json.Length) {
                    break;
                }

                c = json[index++];
                if (c == '"') {
                    complete = true;
                    break;
                } else if (c == '\\') {

                    if (index == json.Length) {
                        break;
                    }
                    c = json[index++];
                    if (c == '"') {
                        s.Append('"');
                    } else if (c == '\\') {
                        s.Append('\\');
                    } else if (c == '/') {
                        s.Append('/');
                    } else if (c == 'b') {
                        s.Append('\b');
                    } else if (c == 'f') {
                        s.Append('\f');
                    } else if (c == 'n') {
                        s.Append('\n');
                    } else if (c == 'r') {
                        s.Append('\r');
                    } else if (c == 't') {
                        s.Append('\t');
                    } else if (c == 'u') {
                        int remainingLength = json.Length - index;
                        if (remainingLength >= 4) {
                            // parse the 32 bit hex into an integer codepoint
                            uint codePoint;
                            if (!(success = UInt32.TryParse(new string(json, index, 4), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out codePoint))) {
                                return "";
                            }
                            // convert the integer codepoint to a unicode char and add to string
                            s.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)codePoint));
                            // skip 4 chars
                            index += 4;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    s.Append(c);
                }

            }

            if (!complete) {
                success = false;
                return null;
            }

            return s.ToString();
        }

        protected static double ParseNumber(char[] json, ref int index, ref bool success)
        {
            EatWhitespace(json, ref index);

            int lastIndex = GetLastIndexOfNumber(json, index);
            int charLength = (lastIndex - index) + 1;

            double number;
            success = Double.TryParse(new string(json, index, charLength), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);

            index = lastIndex + 1;
            return number;
        }

        protected static int GetLastIndexOfNumber(char[] json, int index)
        {
            int lastIndex;

            for (lastIndex = index; lastIndex < json.Length; lastIndex++) {
                if ("0123456789+-.eE".IndexOf(json[lastIndex]) == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return lastIndex - 1;
        }

        protected static void EatWhitespace(char[] json, ref int index)
        {
            for (; index < json.Length; index++) {
                if (" \t\n\r".IndexOf(json[index]) == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        protected static int LookAhead(char[] json, int index)
        {
            int saveIndex = index;
            return NextToken(json, ref saveIndex);
        }

        protected static int NextToken(char[] json, ref int index)
        {
            EatWhitespace(json, ref index);

            if (index == json.Length) {
                return JSON.TOKEN_NONE;
            }

            char c = json[index];
            index++;
            switch (c) {
                case '{':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_CURLY_OPEN;
                case '}':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_CURLY_CLOSE;
                case '[':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_SQUARED_OPEN;
                case ']':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_SQUARED_CLOSE;
                case ',':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_COMMA;
                case '"':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_STRING;
                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': 
                case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                case '-': 
                    return JSON.TOKEN_NUMBER;
                case ':':
                    return JSON.TOKEN_COLON;
            }
            index--;

            int remainingLength = json.Length - index;

            // false
            if (remainingLength >= 5) {
                if (json[index] == 'f' &&
                    json[index + 1] == 'a' &&
                    json[index + 2] == 'l' &&
                    json[index + 3] == 's' &&
                    json[index + 4] == 'e') {
                    index += 5;
                    return JSON.TOKEN_FALSE;
                }
            }

            // true
            if (remainingLength >= 4) {
                if (json[index] == 't' &&
                    json[index + 1] == 'r' &&
                    json[index + 2] == 'u' &&
                    json[index + 3] == 'e') {
                    index += 4;
                    return JSON.TOKEN_TRUE;
                }
            }

            // null
            if (remainingLength >= 4) {
                if (json[index] == 'n' &&
                    json[index + 1] == 'u' &&
                    json[index + 2] == 'l' &&
                    json[index + 3] == 'l') {
                    index += 4;
                    return JSON.TOKEN_NULL;
                }
            }

            return JSON.TOKEN_NONE;
        }

        protected static bool SerializeValue(object value, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            bool success = true;

            if (value is string) {
                success = SerializeString((string)value, builder);
            } else if (value is Hashtable) {
                success = SerializeObject((Hashtable)value, builder);
            } else if (value is ArrayList) {
                success = SerializeArray((ArrayList)value, builder);
            } else if (IsNumeric(value)) {
                success = SerializeNumber(Convert.ToDouble(value), builder);
            } else if ((value is Boolean) && ((Boolean)value == true)) {
                builder.Append("true");
            } else if ((value is Boolean) && ((Boolean)value == false)) {
                builder.Append("false");
            } else if (value == null) {
                builder.Append("null");
            } else {
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }

        protected static bool SerializeObject(Hashtable anObject, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Append("{");

            IDictionaryEnumerator e = anObject.GetEnumerator();
            bool first = true;
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                string key = e.Key.ToString();
                object value = e.Value;

                if (!first) {
                    builder.Append(", ");
                }

                SerializeString(key, builder);
                builder.Append(":");
                if (!SerializeValue(value, builder)) {
                    return false;
                }

                first = false;
            }

            builder.Append("}");
            return true;
        }

        protected static bool SerializeArray(ArrayList anArray, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Append("[");

            bool first = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < anArray.Count; i++) {
                object value = anArray[i];

                if (!first) {
                    builder.Append(", ");
                }

                if (!SerializeValue(value, builder)) {
                    return false;
                }

                first = false;
            }

            builder.Append("]");
            return true;
        }

        protected static bool SerializeString(string aString, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Append("\"");

            char[] charArray = aString.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++) {
                char c = charArray[i];
                if (c == '"') {
                    builder.Append("\\\"");
                } else if (c == '\\') {
                    builder.Append("\\\\");
                } else if (c == '\b') {
                    builder.Append("\\b");
                } else if (c == '\f') {
                    builder.Append("\\f");
                } else if (c == '\n') {
                    builder.Append("\\n");
                } else if (c == '\r') {
                    builder.Append("\\r");
                } else if (c == '\t') {
                    builder.Append("\\t");
                } else {
                    int codepoint = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                    if ((codepoint >= 32) && (codepoint <= 126)) {
                        builder.Append(c);
                    } else {
                        builder.Append("\\u" + Convert.ToString(codepoint, 16).PadLeft(4, '0'));
                    }
                }
            }

            builder.Append("\"");
            return true;
        }

        protected static bool SerializeNumber(double number, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Append(Convert.ToString(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if a given object is numeric in any way
        /// (can be integer, double, null, etc). 
        /// 
        /// Thanks to mtighe for pointing out Double.TryParse to me.
        /// </summary>
        protected static bool IsNumeric(object o)
        {
            double result;

            return (o == null) ? false : Double.TryParse(o.ToString(), out result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used System.Web.Helpers.Json for encoding and decoding. It decodes into a dynamic types, which is a good match for javascript's dynamic data.