# How can I convert Xml to Json and vice versa in c#

Tags: c#, xml, json

I'm supprized that I couldn't find this question here. there seems to be few approches out there but none really seem to work. I found http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx but it very large. Is there a simple way to convert Xml to Json and vice versa?
Thanks,

Comment: I **think** ADO.NET Data Services (Astoria) will do this automatically - I saw a presentation by MS's Diego Vega where he was testing with cURL, and he used -H accept:application/json [URL] to switch the results from XML to JSON. That's about as simple as you can get. ;-)

Comment: You might elaborate on what you mean by 'large'.  Is the size of the library preventing you from solving the problem in some way?

Comment: There are also several suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571168/what-json-library-works-well-for-you-in-net

Comment: The dll size of Newtonsoft.Json is over 200K, which is too large for me to add to my project.

Comment: Have you considered adding the source directly into your existing project?  You likely would be able to remove the parts you don't need, thus making it smaller.

Comment: I tried, but it seems like I'll need to add it all. Well if there is no choice I will. Thanks.

Comment: 200K is an issue? The size of .NET framework 3.5 is approaching 200 megabytes!

Comment: Yes but .NET framework is usually already installed. It also isn't downloaded from my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=Json&ReleaseId=6987 which is a lighter (and older) version of Json.NET and also requires only .Net framework 2.0 It's only 60K.

Answer (score 0):

Super light solution: http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm