# Use JSON with ASP.NET VB

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net, json

I'm new to asp.net and visual basic.

I have an assigment where I must send queries to the database and the returns data. I would like to convert that data to a json and then use it with jQuery

My idea is make an array (arrayList?) and then convert it to json.

How can i use json with asp.net vb? I'm not allowed to use a webservice yet

---

I forgot to mention that this would be a new module in DNN

Comment: Use any of the libraries discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571168/what-json-library-works-well-for-you-in-net/571200#571200).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use an `ArrayList`, but have a look at the `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the JsonSerializer class to do so

Here is an example creating a list of string objects and converting to json

```
Dim lstString As New List(Of [String])()
lstString.Add("One")
lstString.Add("Two")

Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Return serializer.Serialize(lstString)
```

Put this method in an ashx handler and you can access that from  jQuery using the  getJSON method.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

JavaScriptSerializerclass is available in the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

You may probably convert it to an extension method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056127/40521) and use it wherever you want

Comment: Thanks. It worked good. It returns an array, what if i want an object?

Also, how can make it multidimensional? Like `var[0][3]`  or `var.item.name;`
`var.item.color;`

???

Comment: what object ? you can send your object data as json and in the client you can access that.use the object inside the serialize method and you will get the json for that/